# How to pass variables from one module to another in VBA

Tags: vba, variables, module

I am doing some Labview integration and i want to create a VBA macro that takes that data and plots it. That part i figured out (I am newbie with VBA and programming in general).

Test is run from setup files and in setup files different variables are used between different setups (e.g start /stop number of graphs and similar). I can import a module into VBA from labview however i can pass 9 variables which is not enough. So i wanted to either import another module or a file that i could read/write as it fits the situation.

Any suggestions and/or examples?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use ParamArray for larger numbers of parameters.

Module1 code sheet:

```
Sub main()
    helper 1, 2, 3
    helper 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
End Sub

Sub helper(ParamArray longNums())
    Dim i As Variant
    For Each i In longNums
        Debug.Print i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Immediate window results:

```
 1 
 2 
 3 
 1 
 2 
 3 
 4 
 5 
 6 
 7 
 8 
 9 
 10 
 11
```

See [Passing Arguments to Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263527.aspx) for more information.